# How do I unlock my device for KIES?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-kies

I've got the latest version of KIES installed for a Samsung Galaxy S5 (Verizon).  Currently on the June patch level for Android 6.0.1 (and want to use KIES to update to the September patch level).  However, whenever I connect my phone, KIES says "The connected device is locked - Please enter password on the connected device".  I don't see anywhere to enter a connection password on the device.  I'm in the menu, I can run apps, so I'm already past the screenlock password.  What exactly do I need to do for KIES to be allowed access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

On your phone go to settings > developer options > USB configuration > and enable USB debugging

To enable developer options, go to settings > about phone > and tap on the build number seven times.

(Make sure the phone is unplugged from the computer)

Plug the phone in, pull down the shade from the top, and select the USB options button.  Hit that, select software install.